# Problem in S tabular alignment with text

Tags: tables

I'm facing some troubles in alignin text and numbers in tabular with S option. Here is the code. Anyone could help? It's totally non aligned[image: tabular with S]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs} % 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Ammontare di esposizioni solventi ed in default}
\begin{tabular}{cSSSS}
    \toprule        
    Semestre \tabularnewline di segnalazione & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Solventi } 
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{In default} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\%default} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Tot.} \\
            \toprule
    2014h1 & 31930 & 904   & 2.75\% & 32834 \\
    2014h2 & 26851 & 813   & 2.94\% & 27664 \\
    2015h1 & 21724 & 679   & 3.03\% & 22403 \\
    2015h2 & 12651 & 372   & 2.86\% & 13023 \\
    2016h1 & 10076 & 257   & 2.49\% & 10333 \\
    \toprule
    Tot.  & 103232 & 3025 &  2.93\% & 106257 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:solventidefault}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the problem, precisely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You should use `table-format`.
2. If you put `%` in the header, don't repeat it for every row.
3. Put the `\label` just after the `\caption`.
4. Use `\midrule` for the rules not at the top or at the bottom of the table.
5. You don't need `\multicolumn` with `S` table format unless, for example, you use `\makecell`, generally `{...}` is enough.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Ammontare di esposizioni solventi ed in default\label{tab:solventidefault}}
\begin{tabular}{
    c
    S[table-format=6]
    S[table-format=4]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=6]
    }
    \toprule        
    \makecell{Semestre\\ di segnalazione} & {Solventi} & {In default} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{\% \\ default}} & {Tot.} \\
            \midrule
    2014h1 & 31930 & 904   & 2.75 & 32834 \\
    2014h2 & 26851 & 813   & 2.94 & 27664 \\
    2015h1 & 21724 & 679   & 3.03 & 22403 \\
    2015h2 & 12651 & 372   & 2.86 & 13023 \\
    2016h1 & 10076 & 257   & 2.49 & 10333 \\
    \midrule
    Tot.  & 103232 & 3025 &  2.93 & 106257 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]