# Tabular alignment S table

Tags: tables, align

I'd like to align the word "ammontare" in the center of the column with an S tabular environment but I'm not able to do this even with \multicolumn. Any ideas? I'm sorry for the simple question but I'm new to latex. Thanks[image]

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Risultati dell'analisi di portafoglio con prestiti in corso}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}SS}
\toprule
Soglia      & {\makecell[ll]{Ammontare}} & {\makecell[ll]{Percentuale (\%)}}     
\\ 
\midrule
Capitale            & 634042875         & 100.00    \\
EL - $\sigma$       & 18053730          & 2.84          \\
EL                  & 22997024          & 3.62          \\
EL + $\sigma$       & 27940318          & 4.40          \\
95esimo percentile  & 31967180          & 5.04          \\
99esimo percentile  &  37032052         & 5.84  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:portfolioresultscurrent} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Using an appropriate `table-format` option for the `S` type columns was already the answer to your previous three qustions: [tabular alignment with S](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436517/134144), [S tabular with alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436392/134144), [Problem in S tabular alignment with text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436335/134144)

Comment: I'm almost minded to delete my answer here: as noted, this question is arguably a duplicate of several you've already asked.

Comment: I understood that table-format was aimed to select how much integers and decimals the table shoud take, not the lenght of the column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With no `table-format` give, `siunitx` is using the 'centre the decimal marker' strategy. That works in all cases in the sense no boxes are overfull, but here with no decimal part leaves a lot of blank space. You need to give the package a 'clue':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}S[table-format = 9]S[table-format=3.2]}
\toprule
Soglia      & {Ammontare} & {Percentuale (\%)}     
\\ 
\midrule
Capitale            & 634042875         & 100.00    \\
EL - $\sigma$       & 18053730          & 2.84          \\
EL                  & 22997024          & 3.62          \\
EL + $\sigma$       & 27940318          & 4.40          \\
95esimo percentile  & 31967180          & 5.04          \\
99esimo percentile  &  37032052         & 5.84  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```